# wpf binding user control loaded event no executed

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, events, contentcontrol

I have a usercontrol with a loaded event, when I included this in XAML in my content control it executed the loaded event perfectly.

However, I have changed this to dynamic binding on a content control and now the loaded event is not executed.

The header of my usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DesignSuite.CanvasTools.DrawCanvas"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:DesignSuite.CanvasTools" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
```

I am binding the contentcontrol on the following way using a template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FiniteStateMachineCanvasContentTemplate">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding FiniteStateMachineCanvas}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The Canvas which inherits content control shows up fine, only the loaded event is not executed.

The code for the binding is:

```
public DrawCanvas FiniteStateMachineCanvas { get; set; }

    public FiniteStateMachineCanvasTab (
        string NewName,
        ref Toolstate toolstatemanager,
        ref FiniteStateMachineDescriptor finiteStateMachineDescriptor)
    {
        HeaderText = NewName;
        FiniteStateMachineCanvas = new DrawCanvas(ref toolstatemanager, canvastype_e.CANVAS_FINITESTATE, ref finiteStateMachineDescriptor);
    }
```

Does anyone have a pointer in the good direction?

Answer (score 0):

**solved**

Forgot to execute InitalizeComponent in the new constructor I created, this was the cause of the problems.